# different groups, same pattern- regex cpp

Tags: regex

This is my regex:

```
(^[A-Z]+\s*)(\s*\d+)\s*\[([A-Z]+\s*\d+\s*){1,}\]\s*
```

For code:

```
ABC 4[A 5 B 6 C 7]
```

It is producing now:

```
Group 1: Full match
Group 2: ABC
Group 3: 4
Group 4: C 7
```

I want it to produce 5 groups:

```
Group 1: Full match
Group 2: ABC
Group 3: 4
Group 4: A 5
Group 5: B 6
Group 6: C 7
```

How am I supposed to do that?

Here you can try it: [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/dr1kHY/1)

Comment: No way, match the whole substring with [`^([A-Z]+)\s*(\d+)\s*\[([A-Z\d\s]+)]`](https://regex101.com/r/dr1kHY/2), then you may post-process Group 3 value to get the values you need. You may even run another regex that will look like [`[A-Z]+\s\d+`](https://regex101.com/r/dr1kHY/3)

Comment: It's making whole program much more difficult with spliting, is there really no way to do that?

Comment: What program? You have not mentioned that in the question. It is an XY problem then. Anyway, the number of groups is a static number, set by the number of capturing groups in the pattern. Boost has an option to keep captures, but it is not advised some users.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you only have `3` capture groups. The last group matches multiple times but can only contain **one** of them by the end (the last one).

I think you need to perform two matches. The first one to extract the contents of the braces `[<- stuff ->]` and the second to iterate through its contents:

```
std::string s = "ABC 4[A 5 B 6 C 7]";

std::regex e_outer{R"((^[A-Z]+\s*)(\s*\d+)\s*\[([^\]]+)\]\s*)"};

std::smatch m;
if(std::regex_match(s, m, e_outer))
{
    std::cout << m[0] << '\n';
    std::cout << m[1] << '\n';
    std::cout << m[2] << '\n';

    std::string const inner = m[3]; // new match on this part

    std::regex e_inner{R"([A-Z]+\s*\d+\s*)"};

    std::sregex_iterator const end;
    std::sregex_iterator itr(std::begin(inner), std::end(inner), e_inner);

    for(; itr != end; ++itr)
        std::cout << itr->str() << '\n';
}
```

**Output:**

```
ABC 4[A 5 B 6 C 7]
ABC 
4
A 5 
B 6 
C 7
```