# Regexp extracting function arguments

Tags: c++, regex, parsing

I'm writing a regex to extract every element of a line of a basic C++ function call including parameters.

So far I came with this:

```
(?:([\w]+)((?:->|\.)))?([\w]+)(?:(\()((?:[\w]+|\"[^"]*?\"|))(?:\s*(,)\s*((?:[\w]+|\"[^"]*?\"|)))*(\)))
```

With this example:

```
test->log(IL_Info,"a", b, c)
```

What I am able to achieve is getting those elements

- test
- "->"
- log
- "("
- IL_Info
- "," (the last comma)
- c
- ")"

So I can get the first and last argument (including the last comma) but not everything in between, and I can't quite figure out what.

Actually I'm testing this on. [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/OBNEsX/1)

Here's another list of examples I'm testing it on

```
append(apNewTask)
append(a, b)
pSenderTimer.property("trigger")
pSenderTimer->property("id")
scheduler.runTask(fpSchedulingTask)
```

and they're all working fine as long as there is no more than 2 parameters

Comment: Parsing C++ with regexps is not possible.

Comment: the C++ grammar is incredibly complicated, it is most probably not possible to parse a function call using a regular expression alone. You can do it using `clang`, that that is not what you have asked for.

Comment: You can't capture all the elements of a repeated group (because it is still only one group) so you only get the last of them. You need to parse the parameters separately to the rest of the function call.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51159554/different-groups-same-pattern-regex-cpp

Comment: So the above link is definitely a duplicate but it can't be marked as such because the (correct) answer is not "upvoted"...

Comment: You'll also run into problems when the arguments contain another function call. Regular expressions are not generally good for recursive grammars like this.